# google_contacts_api - undefined method `get' for #<String:0x007fce71ad54e8> Did you mean? gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, google-contacts-api

I'm working to use the google_contacts_api: https://github.com/aliang/google_contacts_api

I have the following code in user.rb:

```
google_contacts_user = GoogleContactsApi::User.new(self.authentications.first.token)
@x = google_contacts_user.contacts
```

`self.authentications.first.token` is the token stored via omniauth-google-oauth2.

Problem is, this is erring:

```
undefined method `get' for #<String:0x007fce71ad54e8> Did you mean? gem
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you check the class of `google_contacts_user`? Its class is other than the `String` class, right?

Comment: Not sure I'm following. What did I do wrong?

Comment: have you try debug `google_contacts_user` ?

Comment: Yes. Is there anything you wanted me to look at in particular?

Comment: Perhaps self.authentications.first.token is a string instead of a OAuth2::AccessToken object as required

Comment: @Joel_Blum any idea how to create an object using omniauth?

Comment: @AnApprentice It's all in the gem's docs "See their respective documentation for details on how to get this object."

Comment: @Joel_Blum really? where? Would you mind pointing me in the right direction. I'm using rails/omniauth to get the google_oauth2 token, I am storing the token and refresh token in my db. I'm not seeing how I use the already obtained token to build a token object... would really appreciate your help. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First install  oauth2

```
 gem install oauth2
```

And then create an Oauth2AccessToken instance from the token string

```
 oauth2_object = OAuth2::AccessToken.new(self.authentications.first.token)
```

Now it should be possible to use this Oauth2AccessToken with the GoogleContacts gem:

```
 GoogleContactsApi::User.new(oauth2_object)
```

I'm basing this on the gem's docs

> You need to pass to the GoogleContactsApi::User constructor one of the
>   following two objects:
>
> an OAuth::AccessToken from the oauth-ruby gem an OAuth2::AccessToken
>   from the oauth2 gem

Comment: Thanks @joel_blum, just gave it a try, the oauth2_object line is erring with "wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2..3)"

Comment: @AnApprentice did u figure it out? I'll edit my answer for future reference